# Right single quote spacing in Micro Hei

Tags: html, fonts

In my Octopress blog. It transfers single quote(`'`) to right single quote(`&rsquo;`).

I am using the font of "Micro Hei", and it displays like this:

[image]

How can I make it be displayed like: **`I'm`**